# Initial value for ReturnType<typeof setInterval> for both browser and node environment

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js

I have an Interval that I need to save and I was wondering how to set the initial value for the `intervalTimer` if the type is `ReturnType<typeof setInterval>`

```
  interface Data {
    intervalTimer: ReturnType<typeof setInterval>
}

var data : Data = {
    intervalTimer: "initial value????",
}

function start(){
    data.intervalTimer = setInterval(()=>console.log('PING'), 3000)
}
```

This should work both on Node and Browser. Which both return different values.
So simply setting `intervalTimer` to 0 results in an error `Type 'Timeout' is not assignable to type 'number'`

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant method, but one option is to set an initial timeout which runs a no-op, to ensure that `intervalTimer`'s initial value is of the expected type regardless of the environment:

```
interface Data {
    intervalTimer: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>
}
const data: Data = {
    intervalTimer: setTimeout(() => void 0),
}
```